# Can't leave text mode once entered

Tags: 14.10, gui, freeze, 32-bit, text-mode

Im using Ubuntu 14.10 32bit And I want to install Nvidia official driver as I've dome many time. But once I press Ctrl+Alt+F1, I enter a stucked command line where I cant press anything also not leaving back to GUI With Ctrl+Alt+F7 (or moving between F's)

Edit: Sometimes when I enter text mode, the splash screen appear on half of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.